# How to write and read a binary PLY file with CGAL?

Tags: c++, cgal, ply-file-format

I can write a binary PLY file with CGAL but I'm not able to read it: either `read_PLY` returns `false` (as in my true code), or it crashes the session (as in the code below, "memory not mapped" error).

While `write_PLY` is successful, it's possible that I don't correctly use it, because I'm not able to read the PLY file with another software as well.

Do you see something wrong in my code below?

```cpp
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/orient_polygon_soup.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/orientation.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/polygon_soup_to_polygon_mesh.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh.h>
#include <CGAL/IO/io.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh/IO/PLY.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel EK;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<EK::Point_3>                   EMesh3;
typedef EK::Point_3                                       EPoint3;
namespace PMP = CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing;

int main() {
    
  // octahedron soup ----------
  double phi = (1.0 + sqrt(5.0)) / 2.0;
  std::vector<EPoint3> vertices = {EPoint3(0.0, 0.0, phi),  EPoint3(0.0, phi, 0.0),
                                   EPoint3(phi, 0.0, 0.0),  EPoint3(0.0, 0.0, -phi),
                                   EPoint3(0.0, -phi, 0.0), EPoint3(-phi, 0.0, 0.0)};
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> faces = {{1, 0, 2}, {0, 5, 4}, {5, 1, 0},
                                         {0, 2, 4}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 5, 1},
                                         {2, 3, 4}, {5, 3, 4}};
  bool success = PMP::orient_polygon_soup(vertices, faces);
  if(!success) {
    std::cout << "Polygon orientation failed.";
    return 1;
  }

  // make mesh ----------
  EMesh3 mesh;
  PMP::polygon_soup_to_polygon_mesh(vertices, faces, mesh);

  // write to binary PLY file ----------
  std::ofstream outfile;
  outfile.open("octahedron.ply", std::ios::binary);
  CGAL::IO::set_binary_mode(outfile);
  bool ok = CGAL::IO::write_PLY(outfile, mesh);
  outfile.close();
  if(!ok) {
    std::cout << "Writing file failed.";
    return 1;
  } else {
    std::cout << "Writing file successful.\n";
  }

  // read the PLY file ----------
  EMesh3 mesh2;
  std::ifstream infile("octahedron.ply", std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);
  std::cout << "infile is open: " << infile.is_open();
  bool ok2 = CGAL::IO::read_PLY(infile, mesh2);
  infile.close();
  if(!ok2) {
    std::cout << "Reading file failed.";
    return 1;
  }
  
  // print mesh ----------
  std::cout << mesh2;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just noticed one thing: You pass two arguments to `write_PLY` but in the API docs it expects at least 3 arguments i.e. fname, point_set and comments. https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Point_set_3/group__PkgPointSet3IOPLY.html

Comment: @kiner_shah This works like this if I don't set the binary mode. The comments are optional.

Comment: Although the API docs does state it's optional, but API doesn't look like it has some default value for comments. But that's just a side note. API doesn't mention in which cases `read_PLY` can return false. Maybe you can ask them to add some details in their docs (or provide a way to display error messages) for better debugging.

Comment: @kiner_shah Indeed that is strange. But the code would not compile if it were not optional. I already asked this question on the CGAL Github repo, but got no answer.

Comment: Since the file is binary, maybe you can check if the file is of proper format using a hex editor (or hex viewer/dumper). It can also be some bug (some edge case) on their side in their read_PLY function implementation (or write_PLY too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `write_PLY` function of `Surface_mesh/IO/PLY.h`, after writing the header, it will write all vertices data. If you check the `octahedron.ply` file, you will see the ascii number after header, not binary value.

To solve the problem, could you change the kernel to bellow?

```cpp
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel EK;
```

I don't know why `CGAL Surface_mesh` not work correctly with `Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel` kernel. Maybe it's a bug, or a desire behavior.

I explain the current issue as bellow:

- When using `CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel` kernel, each value in `EPoint3` is not a `double` data type, but a `const CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<boost::multiprecision...` type.
- In this case, the data type is `Lazy_exact_nt`, then, when writing vertices data, it call to `operator << Lazy_exact_nt` (file `Lazy_exact_nt.h`), so the data is written wrongly. 
  If the datatype is primitive (check file `io_tags.h`, the datatype with `io_Read_write`) will be written correctly.

Comment: Works better! With the modification you suggest, I can read the file with another software. But still not with `read_PLY`.

Comment: The reading works as well!